# PictureBox Dinâmico

Tags: c#

Tenho uma tabela chamada "Subordinado" onde são cadastrados usuários com suas respectivas fotos. Tenho um form e preciso exibir as fotos de todos os usuários cadastrados.

Pra isso tenho o seguinte método:

```
private void ListarImagens()
{
    strSql = "Select Imagem from Subordinado";

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, sqlCon);

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                fotoArray = (byte[])reader["Imagem"];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fotoArray);
                pic1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);


            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Cada foto cadastrada deve ser mostrada em um PictureBox diferente e não to conseguindo fazer.
Como faço isso?

Comment: E qual é a dúvida/problema?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que está usando winforms e que seu código está no próprio form:

Coloque um FlowLayoutPanel onde quer que as fotos apareçam, e em seguida altere o loop do seu reader:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    fotoArray = (byte[])reader["Imagem"];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fotoArray);
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox(); //Cria um novo picturebox
    pb.Image = Image.FromStream(ms); //carrega a imagem
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom; //define as propriedades do picturebox
    pb.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1; //Coloca o picturebox dentro do FlowLayoutPanel
    pb.Width = 250; //define a largura
    pb.Height = 300; //define a altura

    //Para adicionar um toolTip, basta coloca-lo no Form e usar:
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(pb, "Descrição da imagem");


    //Para criar um evento no pictureBox
    pb.Click += (s, arg) => { 

            //Faz o evento Click
            //s é o seu sender (picturebox que disparou o evento)
            //arg é o EventArgs

    };


    pb.Show(); //exibe o controle

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado. Mas e se eu quiser colocar o evento do Click em cada PictureBox?

Comment: alterei novamente, colocando o evento click. Se precisar de mais alguma coisa, abre uma questão nova que fica melhor =]